# Setup DNS server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, dns

I have a SaaS company and i need to create subdomains automatic for each client. So i have:

- - www.domainA.com , I create two NS, ns1 and ns2 for the same IP (azure public ip).
- After that i change www.domainA.com for that ns1, ns2;
- I Install dns role on Azure vm add i have domainA.com;
- I open DNS port (53) on azure portal;
- I also include domainA.com into DNS server inside VM!

When i do ping to ns1.domainA.com works! but to domainA.com not

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now offers a DNS service as part of Azure. It's in preview, but it is just what you are after. We are using it for SaaS and provisioning new CName records using the REST API:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-overview/